# Store the output of command in variable in unix

Tags: python, variables, unix

Need to check the version of python so for that i am hitting this command in a script.
I am trying to store the output of the given command in a variable "x".So that I can use this x in further script.
But when I am trying to print x it is showing null value(no value).

```
[bin]$x=`/path/thirdparty/python/2.7/bin/python2.7 -V`
Python 2.7.8
[bin]$echo x
```

Please help me to store the value of the command in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python -V` writes to the standard error, not to the standard output. So you have to redirect STDERR (`2`) to STDOUT (`1`).

```
$ x=$({python -V} 2>&1)
$ echo $x
Python 2.7.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm... the output is possibly written to stderr, not stdout. Try this:

```
x=`/path/thirdparty/python/2.7/bin/python2.7 -V 2>&1`
```